# Akka Http singleRequest stream is hanging after multiple requests

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http, actorsystem

I'm trying to request multiple links, one at a time using akka-https `Http().singleRequest`. In my demo code below however the `foldLeft` only ever loops four times and the application never reaches the `println` statements or terminates.

Im using the default akka config, but I'm thinking that the `Http().singleRequest` is consuming my threads and not releasing them. If I change the link list to only include 4 links the application terminates and I can see the `println`. However five and the app will hang during the fifth loop.

Has anyone seen this before or is there a fault with my impl. of the ActorSystem in this specific usecase.

```
val links = List(
  "https://www.google.com/",
  "https://www.google.com/",
  "https://www.google.com/",
  "https://www.google.com/",
  "https://www.google.com/",
  "https://www.google.com/",
  "https://www.google.com/",
  "https://www.google.com/"
)

implicit val as: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
implicit val mat: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

import as.dispatcher

def get(url: String): Future[Either[Throwable, Unit]] = {
  Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = url)) transformWith {
    case Success(_) =>
      Future.successful(Right(()))
    case Failure(e) =>
      Future.successful(Left(e))
  }
}

def getLinks(): Future[Seq[Unit]] = {
  links.foldLeft(Future.successful(Seq.empty[Unit])){
    case (f, e) => f.flatMap { ls =>
      get(e) map {
        case Right(i) => ls :+ i
        case Left(_) => ls
      }
    }
  }
}

getLinks() transformWith{
  case Success(ls) =>
    println("terminated")
    println(ls.length)
    Future.successful(())
  case Failure(e) =>
    println("terminated")
    println(e.getMessage)
    Future.successful(())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consuming (or discarding) the Entity of a request is mandatory (from https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html).

Try to add `response.discardEntityBytes()` to your code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just managed to figure it out from https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/19538, also I could have read the manual here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/request-level.html. I will say through its not a trivial thing to know...